# Building multiple configurations in Service Fabric fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

When creating a new Stateless service the project defaults to x64, however when creating a Web API stateless service the configuration is stuck on AnyCPU and saving an x64 configuration is ignored.

The problem I'm having is that I have a class library project that is referenced by both stateless services (in order to share the definition of the non web api interfaces) and I am stuck choosing between the configuration that matches one or the other of the stateless services configurations.

The solution seems to build fine either way, but when I go to deploy to the local cluster I get build errors as if the class library wasn't built. Consider the following build graph:

- Web API (Any CPU) tries to build referenced class library (x64) -> results in class lib not being built
- Web API (Any CPU) tries to build referenced class library (Any CPU) -> Works
- Other stateless service (x64) tries to build referenced class library (Any CPU) - results in class lib not being built

Naturally I see the problem, but there doesn't seem to be a way force the Web API to use x64.

Comment: In the project properties, go to the 'build' tab, in 'configurations' select 'all configurations' and in 'platform target' select value 'x64'.  Does that help?

Comment: The Web API project is an asp.net core (.net framework) project. You cannot change the configuration platform. If you save and reopen the configuration manager it will only use AnyCPU.

Comment: Oh, you can do a filesystem publish and then select the runtime version to use.

Comment: @LoekD The problem isn't building the solution normally in Visual Studio. The problem is building it in the context of the Azure publish project, whatever it's doing it causes the build to fail because of the issues mentioned above.

Comment: My current workaround is to build the referenced class library for Any CPU and then build it again for x64 so the dll exists under both locations bin\debug and bin\x64. This works for me for now but I would love to get a real solution for this issue. (I didn't have the rep to comment so had to post as answer)

Comment: @TomatoFlavour I ended up going down a different route. Since Service Fabric is designed around micro services the very nature of them means that they are encapsulated and are able to be versioned independently. Building on that concept, I've got a separate repository for each service, and actually each service has it's own Application so that deploying each service is not dependent on sharing a single application manifest. Service fabric has some conventions that are great for getting up and running quickly, but are not really best practice.